# Using multiple docker containers on the same host securely like isolated instances

Tags: security, docker, docker-container

I know, multiple Docker containers can be used in the same host, but can they be used securely like isolated instances? I want to run multiple secure and sandboxed containers such that no container can affect or access others.

For instance, can I serve nginx and apache containers which listen to different ports, with full trust that each container can only access their own files, resources etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filesystem isolation (as well as memory and processes isolation) is a core feature of docker containers, based on the [Linux Kernel abilities](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#linux-kernel-capabilities).

But if you wanted to be completely sure, you would deploy your containers on different nodes (each managed by their own docker daemons), each node being a VM (Virtual Machine) on your host, ensuring a complete sandbox.
Then a [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) or [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) would be able to orchestrate those node and their containers, and make them communicate.

This is normally not needed when you have just a few linked containers: their should be able to be managed in isolation by a single docker daemon. You could use [user namespace](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) for additional isolation.

Plus, using nodes to separate containers implies different machines or different VM within the same machine.
And one big difference with a VM and a container is that a VM will preempt resources (allocate a fix minimal amount of disk/memory/CPU), which means you cannot launch an hundred VM, one per container. As opposed to a single docker instance, where a container, if it does nothing, won't consume much disk space/memory/CPU at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about using VM but I think there is a serious performance loss in this option.

Comment: @Bilal You would need to measure it, but the overhead is quite minimal these days with Hypervisor 2, and *very* minimal with Hypervisor 1 (bare-metal like Hyper-V on Windows) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor)

Answer (score 2):

In some sense you are asking the million dollar question with containers, and to be clear, IMHO there is no black and white answer to the question "is the platform/technology secure enough." It is a big (and important) enough question that the list of startups--not to mention amount of funding they've received--around container security is an appreciable number!

As noted in another answer, isolation for containers is realized through an assortment of Linux kernel capabilities (namespaces and cgroups), and adding more security to these capabilities is **yet another** set of technologies like seccomp, apparmor (or SELinux), user namespaces, or general hardening of the container runtime & node it is installed on (e.g. via the [CIS benchmark guidelines](https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/docker/)). Out of the box default installation and default runtime parameters are probably **not** good enough for generically trusting in the kernel isolation primitives of Linux. However, this depends greatly on the *trust level* of **what** you are running across your container workloads. For example, is this all in-house within one organization? Can workloads be submitted from external sources? Obviously the spectrum of possibilities may greatly impact your level of trust.

If your use case is potentially narrow (for example, you mention web serving content from nginx or apache), and you are willing to do some work to handle base image creation, minimization and hardening; add to that a `--readonly` root filesystem and a capability limiting apparmor and seccomp profile, bind mount in the content served + writeable area, with no executables and ownership by an unprivileged user--all those things together might be **enough** for a specific use case.

However, there is no guarantee that a currently unknown security escape becomes a "0day" for Linux containers in the future, and that has led to promotion of **lightweight virtualization** that marries container isolation with actual hardware-level virtualization through shims from [hyper.sh](https://docs.hyper.sh/Introduction/why_hyper_.html) or [Intel Clear Containers](https://clearlinux.org/features/intel%C2%AE-clear-containers), as two examples. This is a happy medium between running a full virtualized OS with another container runtime and trusting kernel isolation with a single daemon on a single node. There is still a performance cost and memory overhead to adding this layer of isolation, but it is much less than a fully virtualized OS and work continues to make this less of a performance impact.

For a deeper set of information on all the "knobs" available for tuning container security, a presentation I gave last year several times is available on [slideshare](https://www.slideshare.net/PhilEstes/docker-london-container-security) as well as [via video](https://www.linux.com/news/docker-london-container-security-video) from Skillsmatter.

The incredibly thorough "[Understanding and Hardening Linux Containers](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/our-research/understanding-and-hardening-linux-containers/)" by Aaron Grattafiori is also a great resource with exhaustive detail on many of the same topics.